# PropertyGrid handling unknown types / custom properties

Tags: c#, properties, xna, propertygrid

I've just tried using the PropertyGrid for my "Game Editor" so to edit Objects and such easier, but how do you handle unknown types?

For instance I use XNA and Texture2D is a type of the XNA Framework (others work well, such as Point/Vector) but Texture2D is just a bitmap at it's core, so is there a way to "handle" unknown types and customize how the PropertyGrid can show them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [TypeConverters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ayybcxe5%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

There are generic type converters that inherit from TypeConverter and provide basic behaviours, one of the most useful is [ExpandableObjectConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.expandableobjectconverter.aspx), that you can use to expand class instances.

```
    [TypeConverter( typeof( ExpandableObjectConverter ) )]
    public PhysicsObject Physics { get; private set; }
```

This is an example of my Point3 structure and its custom type converter:

```
namespace Microsoft.Xna.Framework
{
#if WINDOWS
    public class Point3Converter: System.ComponentModel.ExpandableObjectConverter
    {
        public override bool CanConvertFrom( System.ComponentModel.ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType )
        {
            return sourceType == typeof( string );
        }

        public override object ConvertFrom( System.ComponentModel.ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, object value )
        {
            try
            {
                string[] tokens = (( string ) value).Split( ';' );
                return new Point3( int.Parse( tokens[0] ), int.Parse( tokens[1] ), int.Parse( tokens[2] ) );
            }
            catch
            {
                return context.PropertyDescriptor.GetValue( context.Instance );
            }
        }

        public override object ConvertTo( System.ComponentModel.ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType )
        {
            Point3 p = ( Point3 ) value;
            return p.X +";"+ p.Y+";" + p.Z;
        }
    }

    [System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter( typeof( Point3Converter ) )]
#endif
    public struct Point3
    {
        public int X,Y,Z;

        public static readonly Point3 UnitX = new Point3( 1, 0, 0 );
        public static readonly Point3 UnitY = new Point3( 0, 1, 0 );
        public static readonly Point3 UnitZ = new Point3( 0, 0, 1 );

        public Point3( int X, int Y, int Z )
        {
            this.X = X;
            this.Y = Y;
            this.Z = Z;
        }

        public static Vector3 operator +( Point3 A, Vector3 B )
        {
            return new Vector3( A.X + B.X, A.Y + B.Y, A.Z + B.Z );
        }

        public static Point3 operator +( Point3 A, Point3 B )
        {
            return new Point3( A.X + B.X, A.Y + B.Y, A.Z + B.Z );
        }

        public static Point3 operator -( Point3 A, Point3 B )
        {
            return new Point3( A.X - B.X, A.Y - B.Y, A.Z - B.Z );
        }

        public static Point3 operator -( Point3 A )
        {
            return new Point3( -A.X, -A.Y, -A.Z );
        }


        public override string ToString( )
        {
            return X+";"+Y+";"+Z;
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: Since classes with "default datatypes" work, this is not needed. I can easily just add a class with a few Vector3/Point (from XNA Framework) without needing to convert a type. But for types that are similiar to others: Texture2D -> Image, I want some kind of example for that.

Comment: So, PropertyGrid handles Vector3 and Point and such without me needing to customize anything.

Comment: you are asking about custom datatypes, and this is the way that propertygrid handle them... it would great if are more more specific with an example of what you want to do..

Comment: Well, I asked about Texture2D and specifially wrote that datatypes with "default types" works already, like Point, Vector2, Vector3, and so on. Structs containing defeault types (int, float, double, string and such).

Comment: you are not clear with the difference between "custom" and "default" types, Texure2D is defined in the xna framework as Vector3 or Point are. But these have a DataType converter. If you create a type, that I think is a "custom" type, you should use a TypeConverter, but if you want customize what properties show in a general way, you can use a custom PropertyTab and custom PropertyDescriptors, here you are an example http://www.ozcandegirmenci.com/post/2008/08/Extending-PropertyGrid-Adding-custom-PropertyTab-and-PropertyDescritors.aspx, you'll realize that it's a more hardcore solution...

Answer (score 0):

you are not clear with the difference between "custom" and "default" types, Texure2D is defined in the xna framework as Vector3 or Point are. But these have a DataType converter. If you create a type, that I think is a "custom" type, you should use a TypeConverter, but if you want customize what properties show in a general way, you can use a custom PropertyTab and custom PropertyDescriptors, here you are an example ozcandegirmenci.com/post/2008/08/…, you'll realize that it's a more hardcore solution... – Blau

The [http://www.ozcandegirmenci.com/post/2008/08/Extending-PropertyGrid-Adding-custom-PropertyTab-and-PropertyDescritors.aspx](http://www.ozcandegirmenci.com/extending-propertygrid-adding-custom-propertytab-and-propertydescritors/) link has been changed. You can reach here.

New Link : http://www.ozcandegirmenci.com/extending-propertygrid-adding-custom-propertytab-and-propertydescritors/